# How to push into a certain folder from master

Tags: git

I have to push to master branch a local folder into a specific folder from master.

1. git init
2. git add masterURL -> contains proiect folder
3. git add.
4. git push -u origin master

!! how can I push my changes into proiect folder from master.
Please help!
PS: so all my changes would be in proiect folder not at the same level as proiect

Comment: That's not how Git works. Clone the repository, add your files, commit, push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git isn't designed that way. A Git repository tracks full snapshots of a complete project tree. You cannot push a single subdirectory and you cannot push (unrelated) commits and expect them to show up in antoher branch.

Here's what you can do:

1. Clone the repository
2. Optional: create and checkout a feature branch
3. Copy your files/directories and `git add` them
4. Remove any files you no longer need (`git rm`)
5. Commit the new state with `git commit`
6. Push the new commit
7. Optional: create a pull request or merge request to integrate your branch into the master branch

Read an extensive overview in the [Contributing to a Project](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project) chapter of the Git book.